# MySQL results to JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I've seen lots of similar question on here, but I haven't been able to get my desired output. Could someone please help me out? How can generate the following JSON structure? My query is fine, I just can't figure out how to loop through and get this. Thanks

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "id": 271,
            "fname": "Carlos",
            "lname": "Beltran",
            "position": "OF",
            "stats": [
                {
                    "year": "2010",
                    "hr": 32,
                    "rbi": 99,
                    "team": "NYM"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2011",
                    "hr": 35,
                    "rbi": 100,
                    "team": "STL"
                }, 
                {
                ............
                }
            ]
        },
        {
          ........
        }
    ]
}
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
{"0":{"cbs_id":"18817","fname":"Carlos","lname":"Beltran"},"stats":[{"year":"2007","hr":"33","rbi":"112"}]}

{"0":{"cbs_id":"174661","fname":"Willie","lname":"Bloomquist"},"stats":[{"year":"2007","hr":"2","rbi":"13"}]}

{"0":{"cbs_id":"1208693","fname":"Brennan","lname":"Boesch"},"stats":[{"year":"2010","hr":"14","rbi":"67"}]}
```

Which is generated with: (I know I'm way off)

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

        $player = array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {

            $player[] = array (
            'cbs_id' => $row['cbs_id'],
            'fname' => $row['fname'],
            'lname' => $row['lname']
            );

            $player['stats'][] = array(
                'year' => $row['year'],
                'hr' => $row['hr'],
                'rbi' => $row['rbi']
            );

        }

        $json = json_encode($player);
        echo "<pre>$json</pre>";

        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
}
```

NOTE: Each player can have more than one "stats" record (year, hr, rbi, etc)

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may give what you want:

```
$players = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  $id = (int)$row['cbs_id'];

  if ( ! isset($players[$id]))
  {
    // New player, add to $players array.
    // For the moment index players by ID so stats can be easily added
    // to an existing player. Without indexing (using $players[] = ...),
    // the same player would be added for each stats record related to
    // him.
    $players[$id] = array(
      'id'       => $id,
      'fname'    => $row['fname'],
      'lname'    => $row['lname'],
      'stats'    => array()
    );
  }

  // Add the stats
  $players[$id]['stats'][] = array(
    'year' => (int)$row['year'],
    'hr'   => (int)$row['hr'],
    'rbi'  => (int)$row['rbi']
  );
}

// Players are indexed by their ID in $players but need to be contained in
// a JSON array, so use array_values() to remove indices, e.g. convert
//
//     array(
//       271 => array('id' => 271, ...),
//       ...
//     )
//
// to
//
//     array(
//       array('id' => 271, ...),
//       ...
//     )
//
$data = array('players' => array_values($players));
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Eventually you might leave out the integer casts and let PHP automatically convert stringified numeric data (that's the default behaviour with MySQL query results) back to PHP numbers by using the **MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE** mysqli connection option as described in example #5 of [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php). Note that it requires the mysqlnd library to be used by PHP (you can check that with `phpinfo`).

Answer (score 2):

You need an associative array. Something like this should get you *started*:

```
$data = array(
    'players' => array(
        array(
           'id' => 271,
           'fname': 'Carlos',
           'lname': 'Beltran',
           'position': 'OF',
           'stats' => array(
               array(
                   'year' => 2010,
                   'hr': 32,
                   'rbi': 99,
                   'team': 'NYM'
               ),
               ...
           )
        ),
        ...
    )
);
```

To encode it into json, use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that I'm having issues building the array correctly

Comment: I updated my question. I know I'm way off, but I've been staring at this for way too long.

Comment: WHy not take the JSON that you have (the 1 line thing), and just use that?