# Convert results from Sql to Json

Tags: php, sql, json

I have this code php

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM hosts where cod='$stream'";
    $result2=mysql_query($query2);
    while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
    {
$audio=$row2['audio'];
$def=$row2['def'];
$hosty=$row2['host'];   
    }
```

How I get the results to json in this format :

```
var sources = {"english":{"360":["bayfiles","filebox","zalaa","cramit"],"720":["cramit","180upload"]},"portugues":{"1080p":["zalaa","cramit"],"720":["cramit","180upload"]}}
```

is possible?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: There is no such thing as "sql results". Variables in php are exactly the same regardless of where the actual data came from

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594939/mysql-results-to-json-with-php?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an output array with all queries should use an auxiliar array, to go getting each row.

```
 $arrayAux=array();
 $query2 = "SELECT * FROM hosts where cod='$stream'";
    $result2=mysql_query($query2);
    while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
        $audio=$row2['audio'];
        $def=$row2['def'];
        $hosty=$row2['host'];  
        push_array(array("audio"=>$audio,"def"=>$def,"host"=>$hosty)); 
    }
  print(json_encode($arrayAux));
```

PS: I did not understand if you wanted to remove all queries or only applied to one.
If it was only one:

1. Eliminates arrayAux.
2. Eliminates the while.
3. And make directly a `print (json_encode (mysql_fetch_array ($ query2,
   MYSQL_ASSOC)));`

Comment: my solution $query2 = "SELECT * FROM hosts where cod='$stream'";
 $result2=mysql_query($query2);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
{
  $audio = $row['audio'];
$def=$row['def'];
$hosty=$row['host'];

 
 $players[$audio][$def][] = array(
    $hosty, );
}

$data = ($players);
$json = json_encode($data);
 thanks everbody

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP Function [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and pass it in an array matching the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by using PHP's  [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

> **json_encode** — Returns the JSON representation of a value

However, in order to get a multidimensional object, you might have to execute more queries or possibly iterate over some of the values you got from your first query.  Then you would build the data in a multidimensional PHP array and execute the `json_encode()` function on the entire object.

```
$arr = array(
  'a' => 1, 
  'b' => 2, 
  'c' => array(
    'd'=>3,
    'e'=>4
  )
);

echo json_encode($arr);


{
  "a":1,
  "b":2,
  "c":{ 'd':3,"e":4}
}
```